# How to redirect file I/O operations of a process to memory or a different file?

Tags: memory, process, redirection, io, file-io

Let's say I have a file named **file.txt** and a *running* process with **PID 12345** which sometimes reads and sometimes writes to that file.

1. Is there any way I can fool the process with **PID 12345** to read or write to memory (allocated by another process) every time it tries to read or write to **file.txt**?
2. Is there any way I can fool the process to read and write to a different file (like **file2.txt**)?

On **Windows**.

[Same question for Unix/Linux.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385038)

Comment: Simple I/O redirection is similar in Unix/Linux and Windows.  Something like what you want, if it's possible at all, will probably be very different.  I suggest that you edit this question to be Windows-only, and ask a second question that is Linux-only, and link them. The Linux question might fare better on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [You need to hook call to Windows API](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intercepting-system-api-calls)

Comment: When you learned, how to substitute file, you can use [RAMdisk](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/create-10-gbs-ram-disk-windows/)